# Expand the function $f(x)=(1+x)^m$ using Taylor's theorem thus, representing this function as a sum of infinite number of terms in a suitable interval

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, taylor-expansion

Expand the function $f(x)=(1+x)^m$ using Taylor's theorem thus, representing this function as a sum of infinite number of terms in an appropriate interval.

The solution presented was as follows:

> The function $f(x)=(1+x)^m$ leads to
> $f(x)=m(m-1)(m-2)\cdots(m-n+1)(1+x)^{m-n},f(0)=m(m-1)(m-2)(m -n+1).$
>
> $R_n$(Cauchy) $=\frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}(1-\theta)^{n-1}f^n(\theta x)=\frac{m(m-1)(m-2)\cdots(m-n+1)x^n}{(n-1)!}(1+\theta x)^{m-1}(\frac{1-\theta}{1+\theta x})^{n-1},$ and $f^n(x)$ exists for every value of $x,$ when $m$ is a positive integer and $f^n(x)$ exists for every valne of $x > -1,$ when $m$ is negative integer or fraction.
>
> Now, $$(1+x)^m=f(0)+hf'(0)+ \frac{h^2}{2!}f''(0)+\cdots +\frac{h^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f^{n-1}(0)+R_n=1+mx+\frac{m(m-1)}{2}x^2+\cdots +\frac{m(m-1)(m-2)\cdots(m-n+2)}{(n-1)!}x^{n-1}+R_n$$
>
> Case 1. If $m$ be a positive integer, the expansion ends after tho $(m+ 1)th$ term, because of the presence of the factor $(m-n+ 1)$ will make every following term zero. Hence,
> $$(1+x)^m=1+mx+\frac{m(m-1)}{2}x^2+\cdots $$
> is valid for every value of $x.$
>
> Case 2. If however $m$ be any real number, not necessarily a positive
> integer, then for the determination of $R_n$  when $|x|< 1,$ we observe that
>
> (i)  $\frac{m(m-1)(m-2)\cdots(m-n+1)x^n}{(n-1)!}\to 0,$ as $n\to\infty,$
>
> (ii) $(l+\theta x)^{m-1}$ is fnite,
>
> (iii) $|\frac{1-\theta}{1+\theta x}|\lt 1$ and hence, $$(\frac{1-\theta}{1+\theta x})^{n-1}$$ is bounded
>
> and hence $R_n\to 0 $ as $n\to\infty.$ Thus for any index,$$(1+x)^m=1+mx+\frac{m(m-1)}{2}x^2+\cdots ,$$ is valid when $|x|\lt 1.$

---

However, it seems that they are using Taylor's Theorem for Cauchy Form of Remainder $R_n$ which states that:

> Let $f:[a,a+h]\to \Bbb R$ and $0\lt h$ such that
>
> - $f^{n-1}$ is continuous in $[a,a+h]$ (#)
> - $f^n$ exists in $(a,a+h)$ (##)
>
> then $f(a+h)=f(a)+hf'(a)+ \frac{h^2}{2!}f''(a)+\cdots +\frac{h^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f^{n-1}(a)+R_n,$ where $R_n=\frac{x^n(1-\theta)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f^{(n)} (a+\theta h) ,$ with $\theta\in(0,1)$.
>
> Again, if $a=0$ then we get, $f(h)=f(0)+hf'(0)+ \frac{h^2}{2!}f''(0)+\cdots +\frac{h^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f^{n-1}(0)+R_n\tag 1$

---

Also, it becomes apparent, that they are using form $(1)$ in their solution. However, I feel that they are ignoring one crucial point, i.e $f$ must satisfy the two conditions $f$ , # and ## in a closed interval. But the domain of $f$ they are using, seems to be $(-1,1)$ and this is clearly not closed. So, my question is, just how are they using the Taylor's Theorem, even when the conditions for using it, is not satisfied?

Comment: They are considering the closed intervals $[-1+1/n, 1 - 1/n]$ for $n = 2,3,....$. Any $x \in (-1,1)$ falls into one of these intervals. It is a trivial calculation to show that $f$ is infinitely differentiable in these intervals.

Comment: You had raised this issue of open intervals for one of my answers to your previous question. Remember the Taylor formula $(1)$ works whenever the conditions are met for $[0,h]$ (#condition) and $(0,h)$ (##condition). Now let $x\in(-1,1)$ and set $h=x$. Confirm that the desired conditions are met in $[0,h]$ and $(0,h)$ (or in $[h, 0],(h,0)$ if $h$ is negative).

Comment: Remember that Taylor theorem is not applied here to the domain of the function involved, but rather to a closed interval which is a subset of the domain. And the simpler version $(1)$ is used for intervals of the form $[0,h]$ or $[h, 0]$.

Comment: I think your confusion is due to the declaration $f:[a, a+h] \to\mathbb{R} $ at the beginning of theorem which suggests that domain of the function is a closed interval. However this is not a necessity. We can instead write $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ and require the existence of $a, h$ such that $[a, a+h] \subseteq A$. This doesn't change anything.

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed  Can I assert, that $f(x)=(1+x)^m$ is differentiable everywhere in $\Bbb R-\{1\}$ because  we have  $$f^{n}(x)= m(m-1)...(m-n+1)x^{m-n}$$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ when $x\neq 1$ ?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I followed your suggestion by considering the intervals $[0,x]$ where $0<x<1$ and applying Taylor's theorem in each such intervals to arrive at the conclusion, that $f(x)=f(0)+xf'(0)+\frac{x^2}{2!}f''(0)+\cdots+\frac{x^{n-1} f^{n-1}(x)}{(n-1)!}+R_n,$ where $R_n=\frac{x^n}{n!}f^n(\theta x)$ (if, we apply Lagrange's form of Remainder or $R_n=\frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}(1-\theta)^{n-1}f^{n}(\theta x)$ if, we apply Cauchy's form of Remainder) when $x\in (0,1).$ Next, my aim was to show, $\lim R_n=0$ but this is the place where I am stuck. I couldn't show, that $\lim R_n=0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  Any idea how to show, $\lim R_n=0$ ?

Comment: I wrote a blog post long back on this problem. See https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2016/07/the-general-binomial-theorem-part1.html?m=0

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Can you please explain how $\frac{m(m-1)(m-2)\cdots(m-n+1)x^n}{(n-1)!}\to 0,$ as $n\to\infty$ ?

Comment: Use ratio test to conclude that it tends to $0$. I have discussed this part as well in the blog post.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks a ton! I got it...